# String Date to LocalDate conversion

Tags: java, string, java-time, localdate, datetime-parsing

My application is giving a Date format and I am trying to convert that string to LocalDate.Here is my code

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DateStringUtil {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
        //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
        String date ="26 Aug 2019 09:46:09,469";
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);


    }

}
```

I am getting error. Any idea how to solve it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '26 Aug 2019 09:46:09,469' could not be parsed at index 2
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalDate.parse(Unknown Source)
at src.DateStringUtil.main(DateStringUtil.java:24)
```

Comment: Your date format string is wrong: it would expect `"26/08/2019 09:46"`. Look into the documentation to work out what pattern you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: If my input Date format is different and I want the output in a different format , have to go with SimpleDateFormat ?

Comment: Just create a second `DateTimeFormatter` and call [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) with it on your `LocalDate` (updated answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date time format does not match the input date:

- Your format expects a date in the `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm` pattern: `26/08/2019 09:46`.
- Your date string is a date in the `dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss,SSS` pattern: `26 Aug 2019 09:46:09,469`

The Java `DateTimeFormatter` documentation has more information on the patterns you can use: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Edit: If you then want to output the local date in a different format, create a second `DateTimeFormatter` and pass it to the [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) method.

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DateStringUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter inputDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS");
        String date = "26 Aug 2019 09:46:09,469";
        LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.parse(date, inputDtf);

        DateTimeFormatter outputDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        String outputDate = ld.format(outputDtf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Last line I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: ClockHourOfAmPm        . ld is coming as 2019-08-26,  no Time components are there. So if we try to format that date to hh:mm:ss how it will work? Any other way ?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT use `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`. I have also changed the `hh` to `HH`, as the latter is 24-hour clock while the former is 12-hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

You input date should be same of the format specified in `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");`

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
    //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
    String date ="26/08/2019 09:46";
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);

}
```

You may want to refer this [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for formats.

Comment: Normally we change the code to match the input data, not the other way around.

Comment: @BillyBrown That was just an example to point out what was going wrong, Thanks for downvoting.

Comment: If you're only pointing out what's wrong, then use a comment.

Comment: Thanks, take a +10 and be happy